# Vue 3 - How to use reactive ref and computed without .value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

When we use [Options API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-api.html), we can define some properties in the  `computed` section and some properties in the `data` section. All of them become accessible from the instance through the `this` reference, i.e. in the same object. It's very suitable.

For example:

```js
if (this.hasMore) {
   this.loading = true;
   ...
}
```

Where `hasMore` is a computed property, `loading` is a reactive property.

Is there any possibility to do something similar via [Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html)? For example, to implement similar code, but where `pagination` is a simple object, not a link to a component, like:

```
if (pagination.hasMore) {
   pagination.loading = true;
   ...
}
```

The [`computed`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#computed) is not solution at all, because it returns `ref` and its using will be completely different than using of `this` in the example above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a `reactive` object having a property which is a computed.  Then it will all be accessible the way you want:

```js
const pagination = reactive({
  loading: false,
  hasMore: computed(() => {
    return true;
  })
})
```

Demo:

```js
const { createApp, reactive, computed } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const pagination = reactive({
      loading: false,
      hasMore: computed(() => {
        return true;
      })
    })
    if (pagination.hasMore) {
      pagination.loading = true;
      // ...
    }
    return {
      pagination
    }
  }
});
app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ pagination }}
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.7/vue.global.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you really dislike having to use .value with ref you might be interested in the Reactivity Transform compiler macro.

Update for 2023:
Reactivity Transform feature will not be added to Vue 3 as a core feature. Instead, add the feature using the Vue Macros library. https://vue-macros.sxzz.moe/features/reactivity-transform.html

```
// declaring a reactive variable backed by an underlying ref
let count = $ref(1)
console.log(count); //no .value needed!
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import ReactivityTransform from '@vue-macros/reactivity-transform/vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [ReactivityTransform()],
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Hope one day `Vue` will get rid of this annoying `.value` suffixes and follows `Svelte` neat approach.