# Vue 3 - can i avoid using .value everywhere?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm quite new to Vue 3 and i'm struggling a lot to understand some concepts of the composition API.
I'm trying to port a library i'm using from vue 2 to vue 3, and in a parent element a reactive property called `layout` is passed to children components.

So in the parent component i'm returning `layout` to the children like this:

```
setup(props){
    const layout = ref({'width': 10, ... })
    return {
        layout,
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that, in order to access `width` or any other reactive value in `layout` from any children component i need to use the syntax `layout.value.width`. This is quite a problem because through the whole project `layout` is referenced with `layout.width`, this means that i need to add a `.value` to every reference to `layout` and do the same for all the other reactive variables i'm passing to my children components. Is there any way to avoid this or am i just not getting some important concepts from the composition api?

Comment: [take a look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977470/vue-3-how-to-use-reactive-ref-and-computed-without-value). hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways:

1. Yes. You can work without the `.value`. You have to use the [vue experimental version](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/369)

or

2. You can create a `reactive` variable, like:

```
<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const layout = reactive({'width': 10, ... })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between reactive and ref?

Comment: In my understand it's like: `ref` is for single values, like one number, a boolean and `reactive` is for an object. There are couple of articles about this.

Answer (score 1):

The reactivity transform feature will automatically append .value onto your reactive variables using $ref(). This experimental feature was announced it is being phased out of Vue core features. Instead, use the stable Vue Macros plugin to banish .value syntax. https://vue-macros.sxzz.moe/features/reactivity-transform.html